# Views 3 Template or UI question

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a text field that contains multiple values. That field does not always contain any values. The field needs to have a label when displayed.

IOW, the row should look like one rows below

CoAuthor: Person X, Person Y

or

CoAuthor: Person X

Here is my issue: When I use the view UI to add the label I get

CoAuthor: Person X, CoAuthor: Person Y

When I use the template,

```
print $fields['field_coauthor']->content;
```

I can not hide the field when empty so I end up with

CoAuthor: (and no value)

Is there a way to add a conditional to the template so that I do not end up with a label and no data? Or configure the view to include the label once... and not add it for every entry?

Answer (score 0):

I am actually a bit puzzled by your View result, because the default settings for fields should give you:

> CoAuthor: Person X, Person Y

when there is more than one author (and this I presume, is what you want?)

And since Views also have a setting: "Hide if empty" under *No results behavior", it should be trivial to get this right using fields.

Anyway, this is how I've set this up using Views:

First, I click on *Format - Show: Content* and switch that to *Fields*.

Second, I tick *Provide default field wrapper elements* and *Hide empty fields*.

Third, under *Fields* I click *Add* and add the "CoAuthor" field. I tick *Create a label*, and *Place a colon after the label*. Under *Multiple field settings*, I tick *Display all values in the same line*.  I also tick *Simple separator* and make sure it is `,`  (comma followed by space, which is the default).Then under *No results behavior*, I leave *No results text* blank, and tick *Hide if empty* and *Hide rewriting if empty*.

Fourth, I navigate to *Format - Show: Settings* and tick to make sure *CoAuthor* is an inline field.

After doing all this, the output should be nothing if there are no CoAuthor, and for the other two cases:

> CoAuthor: Person X
>
> CoAuthor: Person X, Person Y

As for using a template, you should be able to wrap the PHP generating the output in a test that checks for a non-empty field, e.g.:

```
if (!empty(print $fields['field_coauthor']->content)) {
```

I not sure where the template fragment you post come from, so I haven't posted the full code, but I hope you get the idea.